# Why does systemd clean environment variables?

Tags: linux, systemd

Why is it so that `systemd` cleans up environment variables for the child processes ?

Answer (score 2):

This design results in a more reliable, consistent, explicit and potentially safer environment for the child process to execute in.

Consider a case where the child process has a security flaw that can be triggered through setting an environment variable, and the parent process having a flaw that allows setting that environment variable.

As documented in [man systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), you can use `Environment=`, `EnvironmentFile=` and `PassEnvironment=` to explicitly manage additional environment variables.

Controlling a process through environment variables is an example of an "action at a distance" design where mutable global state triggers changes far away in the app. Because where the variables are declared are not near where they are used, there's more opportunity for confusion, bugs and unexpected behavior. Extra rigor and explicitness here reduces the associated risks.